# Java lwjgl variable being changed somehow

Tags: java, arraylist, lwjgl

```
public void newUnit(int type) {  //fix start locations

    switch(type) {
        case 1:{
            System.out.println(spawn);
            LightUnit lw = new LightUnit();
            lw.setLocation(spawn);

            units.add(lw);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            units.add(new MedUnit(spawn));
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            units.add(new HeavyUnit(spawn));
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I have this switch statement which creates a new unit derived from Baseunit and stores it in an array list(units) of type baseunit. When I first create a unit it is displayed at its spawn 0,0. However once I move the unit then try to create another the variable spawn has been updated to the location the first unit is now in. I don't understand because there is not call to the variable ever again but some how its being updated.

```
public void move(BaseUnit e, Vector2f direction) {  
    e.move(direction);
    turnover = true;
}
```

The player has this move method with passes the unit and the location of the new tile to to the base unit and sets its new location but some how in here it is being changed. Not sure where else to look for the bug, I've ruled out a rendering problem so maybe something is wrong with my deriving classes.

Comment: What is `spawn`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with lwjgl. Also please provide more code. 
Make sure you don't use the same position reference for both `Unit`s, e.g.: `private Vector2f spawn = new Vecor2f(0,0);
...
unit.setLocation(spawn);`
In `Unit` Class: 
`move(float x, float y) {
    location.x = x;
    location.y = y;
}`
Somwhere (when spawning a new unit):
`spawn.x = 0;
spawn.y = 0`
This will move the first `Unit` too!